# ASP.NET Web API 2 Download Files

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, azure, asp.net-web-api, download

The scenario is that I have a form which upon submission performs mailmerge on a template and creates a word document which is then stored in azure blob storage.

My problem is that I wish to then allow the user to download this file using Web Api 2 and a custom IHttpActionResult

```
public class FileActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private readonly StreamContent _content;
    private readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue _contentType;
    private readonly long? _contentLength;
    private readonly ContentDispositionHeaderValue _contentDisposition;

    public FileActionResult(HttpRequestMessage request, StreamContent content, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, 
        long? contentLength, 
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition)
    {
        _request = request;
        _content = content;
        _contentType = contentType;
        _contentLength = contentLength;
        _contentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }


    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        response.Content = _content;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _contentLength;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = _contentType;
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = _contentDisposition;

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

My Api Controller then has a GetFile method to retrieve the file.

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetFile")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountConnectionString"));
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("MoveInn");
        var blob = await container.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(@"http://xxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/" + fileName);
        var blobExists = await blob.ExistsAsync();
        if (!blobExists)
        {
            return BadRequest("Not Found.");
        }


        var blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();

        var result = new FileActionResult(Request,
            new StreamContent(blobStream),
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue(blob.Properties.ContentType), 
            blob.Properties.Length,
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment"){
                FileName = fileName.Split('.')[1],
                Size = blob.Properties.Length
            });

        return result;
    }
```

This seems to work perfectly in chrome but I am having problems with trying to download the file in IE10/11. The dialog that asks whether you want to open the file, or save the file appears, but the filename of the document is the entire Get Path i.e. GetFile?fileName=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.docx.

When I then try to save this file, I am unable to.

Any assistance would be wonderful!

Comment: Could you should the request and response headers from IE and the request and response headers for chrome.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I have similiar bug in my WebApi

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did anyone find a solution?